# OPENQUERY stored procedure in Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, db2

I am trying to create a stored procedure that is getting values from a linked to our Sql Server DB2 server.In the stored procedure I have this query:

```
DECLARE @CarID nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000)
SET @CarID = '1111'
  SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,''SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Column LIKE ''''' + @CarID + '%' + ''''''')'
  EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Everithing is working fine but when I add the stored procedure to the Entity model the signature of the procedure is:

```
GetUsers(string):int
```

But when I run the procedure returns data rows. How can I modify the procedure to return a data set not an integer?

Comment: Entity doesn't know the returned type for stored procedures. Use a synonym or view instead.

Comment: Thank you . Could you please give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

EF handles a stored procedure somewhat similar as a scalar function. EF doesn't know how many datasets and which columns will be selected in your stored procedure, therefore cannot generate the classes.

Best way to select something on a linked server is with a view.
Simply create the view with the four part name and add it to your EF datamodel. Then EF will be able the generate the class.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vTestTable]
AS
    Select * from [LINKEDSERVER].[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TestTable]
GO
```

Then in .NET

```
var result = db.vTestTable.Where(t=> t.Column.StartsWith(CarId)).ToList();
```